# List category-posts not work properly

Tags: plugins

I have downloaded list=category-post and activated it.  However, when I am just wanting to display a category e.g. `[catlist name="news"]`  it shows all my posts from the site instead of a single category.  I am using WP 3.8.

Comment: Is this a plugin you are talking about and if yes, please share the link to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i can suggest is that you might not have the news category in your wordpress,
else it works perfectly fine if the category is there with either title as news or the category slug as news both works fine.

Make sure you have the specified category and if you do have that then i suggest you to enable the debugging mode to see other errors and solve them first and it will work automatically.